# Visual Studio Code move and make find and replace box larger

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make the find and replace box larger in size.

Bonus: Would also like it to be on the bottom like how the find and replace on sublime is located.

Comment: You can drag the left edge to make it wider.  Otherwise you can't move it.

Comment: Noet that the edge currently can't be dragged in the context of a jupyter notebook

Comment: @Mark just wanted to say thank you. I've been using VS Code almost since the release and I didn't know about this, it was so annoying to have small find/replace textbox!